# Paying for my own online course class to determine whether I can get into the company

Tags: interviewing, test

So I just had this interview with the CEO of this company. He told me that every interviewee is required to take a test on Coursera. If he or she get 80% and above, he will make an offer and I can get reimbursed if I pass the 80% and take the offer. However, if you do pass but did not take the offer or fail the test, you will not get reimburse.

This is for a developer position

Should I give it a shot?
Also, has anyone had this interview experience before?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty shitty practice to me and makes me wonder whether the CEO might somehow (financially) benefit from this arrangement. However, all that matters to you is how badly you need/want the job, and whether you could afford not getting reimbursed.

Comment: What do you mean by the CEO might financially benefit from it? I'm still thinking about it but I have a feeling that this sounds like those chinaman company style and I have no interest in going for another one.

Comment: It sounds horrible to me. If you have no interest, just don't do it.

Comment: As someone worked for Coursera on their tech courses, the assessments on Coursera are very hit or miss and you can retry the assessments until you get above 80%. I've never ever heard of this kind of requirement for a candidate. What does the CEO get if you purchase this course?

Comment: How much is the test? It makes a real difference if it $10 or $1000.

Comment: @jcmack the ceo gets nothing. Only on me. I pass,I get offer letter and take the offer,i reimburse. I fail or didnt take the offee,wont get reimburse.

Comment: @DJClayworth I am from Malaysia so the cost will be around RM300 based from what the CEO stated

Comment: Assuming RM is Malaysian Ringgit (sp?), that's about US$70, without taking relative cost of living and prosperity into account.  This does not sound or smell legitimate to me.  What is the course about?

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm this is for a java class on coursera

Comment: An online test is a terrible way to evaluate how someone will be as an employee. Even if the CEO's claim is legitimate and he gives you an offer for passing the test, I would have serious reservations about the quality of the company and my coworkers who were selected on the same basis.

Answer (score 10):

> So I just had this interview with the CEO of this company. He told me
>   that every interviewee is required to take a test on coursera and if
>   he or she get 80% and above,he will make an offer and I can reimburse
>   if do pass the 80% and take the offer. However,if you do pass but did
>   not take the offer or fail. You will not get reimburse.
>
> Should I give it a shot?

This seems completely ridiculous to me.

Take the test if and only if you really want this job, are sure you can pass the  test, and will definitely accept the offer. Otherwise, walk away.

> Also,has anyone had this interview experience before?

I have never experienced this, nor have I even heard of it.

I personally would never accept those kinds of terms, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

> He told me that every interviewee is required to take a test on
>   Coursera. If he or she get 80% and above, he will make an offer and I
>   can get reimbursed if I pass the 80% and take the offer. However, if
>   you do pass but did not take the offer or fail the test, you will not
>   get reimburse.

Either the CEO is lying to you, or he is just being supremely naive.

The fact is, anyone could impersonate you on Coursera, and some Coursera students even publish all their answers on their blogs/githubs. So even if you passed that Java course with 80%, that still wouldn't mean very much.

Go ahead. Challenge him on this issue. But do not call him a liar. Just tell him that his process can be so easily cheated and that you'd rather not work for a company that doesn't screen its applicants more thoroughly before making them an offer.

Once you say that, I guarantee you that the CEO will come clean.

He'll probably tell you that there is a final test in person (or done over video-conferencing), but that he has been receiving so many resumes of unqualified people, that this initial roadblock is just a way to screen out the worst of those applicants.

After which you'll have two choices. You can either just submit to the process, or you can insist that he tests you right away.

If you're confident in your java knowledge, I think you should just insist that he tests you right away, or you'll walk. That's how a competent programmer would approach the situation.

> Also, has anyone had this interview experience before?

Yes, but not with Coursera.

Sometimes, an interviewer will give you a homework project to be done over a weekend.

Again, it's the same thing. Even if they promise you a job after you complete that homework, it is seldom the case in reality. They will still need to make sure you didn't get help from anyone else. And they often give the same homework assignment to a huge number of candidates.

So even if you complete that homework project perfectly, it's no guarantee you that you'll get the job.